# Finite in probability implies finite expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $T_n$ be a random variable with $T_n=X_1+...+X_n$ where the $X_i$'s are iid. Further we set $N(t)=max\{ n: T_n\leq n\}$.

If $\Pr(N(t)<\infty)=1$, does this implies $\mathbb{E}[N(t)]<\infty$?

I think intuitively yes. Since every $N(t)$ is finite, then in the mean it is also finite. Is that correct?

Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: The converse is true (at least for positive variables): finiteness of expectation implies finiteness of the underlying variable with probability one. One can use the Markov inequality to prove that.

Comment: Hey @yoann, to prove that can I state that $P(Z=\infty)=\lim_{a->\infty}P(Z\geq a)\leq \lim_{a->\infty}E(Z)/a = 0$ ? My main doubt is on the 1st equality

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. that's correct! $P(Z = \infty) = P(\cap_n Z \geq n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(Z \geq n)$.

Comment: @yoann thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Take, for example, $X\sim\text{Cauchy}(0,1)$. Then
$$
\Pr\{|X|<\infty\}=1,
$$
but $\operatorname E|X|=\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that your claim is not correct. It is entirely possible for a variable $X$ to be "finite in probability", meaning $P(X<\infty)=1$, while having infinite mean. One example is the absolute value of a Cauchy distributed variable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), which is finite in probability while having infinite mean.

An explicitly constructed example can be obtained as follows. Consider a variable $X$ which takes its values in the naturals $1,2,\ldots$, and which satisfies
$$
  P(X = n) = \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{6}{\pi^2}.
$$
We then have
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X = n) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} = 1,
$$
by classical infinite series results (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), so $X$ is well-defined. Also, $P(X<\infty) = 1$. However,
$$
  E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(X = n)
       = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty,
$$
as the harmonic series diverges (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). Thus, this variable $X$ is "finite in probability", taking only finite values, while having infinite mean.

Comment: Thank you very much! This example is great and so it is clear to me. Therefore I have to proof the fact in my special case.
So I have $$\mathbb{E}[N(t)]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n P(N(t)=n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (F_n(t)-F_{n+1}(t))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n(t) $$ by a corollary where $F_n$ is the distribution function of $T_n$.

So i know $0 \leq F_n \leq 1$. But that doesnt implie the finitness of $\mathbb{E}[N(t)]$ or does it?

Comment: No, finiteness of $N(t)$ will depend further on the distributions of the $X$'s. So you need more information to determine whether the mean is finite or not...